# Performing operation using Generic and primitive type not working

Tags: java, generics

Trying to learn some basic operations using JAVA-Genric, i tried to make a generic class, which takes a number and does some operation on it and returns the value but its throwing error

**Parent class :**

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

        MathsExec<Integer> my_obj = new MathsExec<Integer>();
        int rst = my_obj.doAddition(100);
        System.out.println("Solution is : "+rst);
     }
}
```

**Generic Class :**

```
class MathsExec<T>{ //didn't extend NUMBER because m strictly sending int values

     T doAddition(T nmbr){
        int k=100;
        T rst;
        rst = nmbr+k;
        return rst;
    }
}
```

**Error :**

> MathsExec.java:6: error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
>
> ```
>     rst = nmbr+k;
>               ^
> ```
>
> first type:  T
>    second type: int
>    where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Object declared in class MathsExec 1 error

I understand why this error is coming(*incompatible types for operation*) but as per generics, type `T` should have been converted to `Integer` before doing the `+` operation...or is there some other explanation i should know????

P.S : please go easy, JAVA is not my strong suite!!

Comment: What if T were a String?. Would multiplication hold good for Strings?. Will the LHS be able to accept whatever type you send?. How will the compiler know that you have not passed an object that cannot be used in mathematical operations?

Comment: @WhoAmI : i have place a comment in my code, that i am `strictly sending numbers for now`..... :)

Comment: Whatever it is, but why are you doing *multiplication* in `doAddition()` method?

Comment: @Keppil : WADR, i am just learning `generics`, and this was one of the scenario i thought of to code for....to explore generics...i understand there are better ways to do it than generics!! :)

Comment: @RohitJain : haha...sorry mate, i forgot to change back the sign....initially i thot it was something to do with `+`...so changed to `*` to check an then forgot to roll it bak...updated question!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor - Yes. But does (how will) the compiler understand your comment?. :). Who has to tell it that you are sending only ints and nothing else?

Comment: @WhoAmI : I am sending values for now, and i am a human, so yes, i will understand it!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic types are not known in compile time. Therefore, you get that compilation error. And it makes sense, because there is no guarantee that your `*` operator will work on your generic type `T`.

A trivial but educational solution might be adding an interface called `Multipliable` and adding the abstract method `multiply()` to it, than calling that method in your `doAddition` method. BTW to do that you need to change your class definition as something like

```
class MathsExec<T extends Multipliable>
```

**Additional clarifications:**

1. We have to come to an understanding that you cannot use operators like `*` for classes, they are for primitive types only.
2. If you have to use generics and you have to do some operations on generic types, you have to keep your compiler happy and assure it that that Generic object, does have that method. And that is through `T extends SomeClass`.
3. If you want to practice generics without using interfaces or abstract classes or whatever, the most common use case is custom data structures. Where it is possible that you do not actually need many operations on the data that you are storing. You just put them in your structure.

Comment: actually i was trying to achieve the operation done on `generic` class itself...so in other words, avoiding `interface`s or `abstract` methods!! :\

Comment: @NoobEditor I understand that, but if you look at my explanation up there, somehow you have to assure compiler that whatever operation you are doing on generic types actually exists in that class.

Comment: yes i understand your solution....its neat...but m looking for a possible explanation, yours is a workaround...+1 though!! :D

Comment: @NoobEditor I am not sure what type of possible explanation you are looking for, but check out my last edit. Maybe it helps

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> // didn't extend NUMBER because m strictly sending int values
> ```

You can do that. `int` primitives will be boxed to `Integer` wrapper. But the issue is, arithmetic operators won't work on generic types. There may be workaround, but it wouldn't be worth of your effort. I would rather provide overloaded method for handling different primitive types.

BTW, you should take two arguments in the `doAddition()` method, and pass the value of `k`, that you're currently hard-coding. This will allow you to re-use this method in any other class too.

Comment: ok..i understand what u explained....but, if i get it right...u mean to say that *arithematic operations can not be done on generic type with primitive types* ?? :\

Comment: @NoobEditor Yes. You can only perform those operations strictly on primitive types, or with primitive and wrapper types.

Comment: so in that case i'll have to do an explicit typecast( *if i am sending the values to a generic class* )...and that wud fail the purpose of generics in the first place..isnt it??

Comment: @NoobEditor Yes, exactly. Or you can just rely on `double` types. If you make your type parameter `<T extends Number>`, then you can call `nmbr.doubleValue()`. Do the operation, and return `double` from it. There also you would need some typecasting. But as you said, generics is really not helping here. I would definitely overload method here.

Comment: i understand `overload` is a better scenario, but  consider the method shown above is just a template....there might be other scenarios which may require generic!!

Comment: its heartbreaking to know that  generics do not allow for `arithematci ops!!` :(

Comment: @NoobEditor We need to know that specific scenario to identify the usage of generics.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49377/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-rohit-jain)

Answer (score 0):

You should do an explicit cast from `T` to `int` if you know for sure that `T` will be casted down to an `int`. The compiler has no way of knowing if that will actually happen, so it will give you that error.